# Python code execution in Perl interpreter

Tags: python, perl

I am a python automation engineer  and joined a new company. Here automation infrastructure is in Perl. Is there any way i can develop scripts/code in python and run in Perl infrastructure. Will appreciate  inputs from experienced folks who knows Perl and python.

Thanks

Comment: Perl can be used to execute any command, including the python interpreter. However given that the company has decided to use Perl, I highly doubt anyone will thank you for deciding to use a different system.

Comment: Is it your assigned task to do this?  I'd learn perl otherwise.  I wouldn't appreciate a block of <some-language> embedded with an interpreter call in a different language, particularly when the company standard differs.  I'm a wizard at z80 assembler, would it be ok for me to embed that?

Comment: What is "Perl infrastructure"???

Answer (score 2):

In theory, there are ways of embedding Python code in Perl, like the [Inline::Python](https://metacpan.org/pod/Inline::Python) module.

In practice, they should not be used. If your company uses Perl, learn Perl. Trying to use Python anyway will just mean that you end up creating code that nobody else can maintain.